# Java: Why does this thread wait when it already holds the lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, osgi

Here is a single thread from a dump that illustrates the problem. No other thread holds the lock 0x00000007d7f78430 yet still it waits.

```
"main" prio=6 tid=0x000000000033b800 nid=0x2478 in Object.wait() [0x000000000257d000]          java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x00000007d7f78430> (a org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$AllTracked)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.waitForService(ServiceTracker.java:456)
- locked <0x00000007d7f78430> (a org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$AllTracked)
at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.getOsgiService(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:190)
at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.getOsgiService(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:165)
at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintTestSupport.createCamelContext(CamelBlueprintTestSupport.java:116)
at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.doSetUp(CamelTestSupport.java:247)
at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.setUp(CamelTestSupport.java:217)
at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintTestSupport.setUp(CamelBlueprintTestSupport.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
```

Comment: you have to hold the lock before you can wait...

Comment: @zhong.j.yu but once you are waiting the monitor is released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.waitForService(long timeout)](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/util/tracker/ServiceTracker.html#waitForService%28long%29) method.

You will see that it is designed to:

> Wait for at least one service to be tracked by this ServiceTracker.

so this is not lock contention - the underlying system is using locks to wait for stuff - which is actually a really good idea in most cases.